# How does a UNICODE environment block look like to start a new process via CreateProcessW() on Windows?

Tags: c++, unicode, environment, createprocess

Essentially, I would like to create a new process and define the environment for it from the parent process. I would like to use [`CreateProcessW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) and pass a (modified) UNICODE environment into `lpEnvironment`, but I'm not sure what the content should look like compared to an ANSII environment block.

The only documentation I really found is on MSDN:

> Note that an ANSI environment block is
>   terminated by two zero bytes: one for
>   the last string, one more to terminate
>   the block. A Unicode environment block
>   is terminated by four zero bytes: two
>   for the last string, two more to
>   terminate the block.

Now I tried to

1. call `GetEnvironmentStrings` and pass it on to the child process
2. call `GetEnvironmentStringsW`  and pass it to the child process
3. modify these blocks with my additional environment strings and pass it on

non of them work

I really only could set `lpEnvironment` to `NULL` to get it to work, but now I would have to change & revert my parents processing environment - is that the way to go here?

(I also did set `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`)

Could anyone please tell me what is so special about `UNICODE` environment blocks - it did work, when I just use `ASCII` stuff and call `CreateProcessA()`...

Comment: You use "UNICODE" but it should "Unicode".   You use "ANSII", but the word is "ANSI" — and also does not mean anything!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you are doing wrong without code. But this works:

```
STARTUPINFO startInfo = {0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = {0};

WCHAR env[] = L"key=value\0key2=value2\0\0";
WCHAR cmdline[] = L"calc";

startInfo.cb = sizeof(startInfo);
if(!CreateProcessW(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, env, NULL, &startInfo, &procInfo))
{
    printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

Perhaps that will give you an idea of what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much tyranid. Apologies- I didn't post any code, but I was more interested in the structure the "env" string. Your are using 2 \0 at the end, while the win documentation talks about 4 \0 characters to end the block (see the quote in my post at the beginning) - do you know if there is a real difference or can I build the environment block the same way I did with ASCII?

Comment: ok - I just tried it again and got it to work now - the trick is NOT to follow MS guidelines and simply use 1 (!) '\0' character to terminate a string and a total of 2 (!) '\0' characters to terminate the block - NOT 4 as they write in their documentation :/

Comment: @Chris - The documentation says each string ends with 2 zero bytes and entire block ends with 4 zero bytes.  Each WCHAR is two bytes.  So L'\0' is 1 zero character in two zero bytes and L'\0\0' is 2 zero characters in 4 zero bytes total.